# Log4J2 - How to disable logging in unit test?

Tags: java, unit-testing, logging, log4j2

I am using Log4J v2.0 Beta3 in my application for logging and I am getting log messages generated when I run my unit tests. I checked the API for some way to set the log level to something like CRITICAL but I could not find any way to change the logger configuration.

In fact, I read this on the log4j2 website:

> Note that unlike Log4j 1.x, the public Log4j 2 API does not expose
>   methods to add, modify or remove appenders and filters or manipulate
>   the configuration in any way.

So with that said. What is the correct way to disable logging from within unit tests?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I found my answer on the log4j2 website under '[Testing in Maven](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#UnitTestingInMaven)'. The recommended way seems to be to place a log4j2-test.xml file in src/test/resources. Placing the xml file into this directory will cause it to be used instead of a log4j2.xml.

Comment: It would be good to provide an answer to specific question "how to disable". This answers "where to place configuration file for tests" instead.

Answer (score 5):

You can disable logging with setting root level to off (`<Root level="off"/>`).

So place log4j2.xml file into src/test/resources with following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="warn">
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="off"/>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

EDIT:
Removed `<!DOCTYPE xml>` (based on suggestion from sprynter) to make xml valid.

Comment: Remove the `<!DOCTYPE xml>` from the answer above for a valid log4j2 config file.

Answer (score 1):

Both the answers from [@Jbug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14160959/1175279) and [@Dove](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53509257/1175279) work as long as you are placing the file in `src/test/resources` of the current module. If your app depends on a library to include `log4j2.xml` it won't work for test runs since library `jar` won't included test classes and resources.